# Ubuntu 18.04 running slow on Mac

Tags: 18.04

I recently installed Ubuntu on my 2008 Macbook, and it is running very slow. In fact, it took 4 minutes and 6 seconds to reach the login screen, and another minute to reach the home screen. Can I fix this, or should I just switch to another distribution?

Comment: Which desktop environment have you installed?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has support until 2021 and might suit you better. It is faster for sure.

Comment: I can recommend to install [Ubuntu MATE](http://ubuntu-mate.org/) (based on [MATE DE](http://mate-desktop.org/)) with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop` on top of running 18.04 LTS. It works well on 10 year old hardware with at least 2 Gb of RAM. And you may want to buy SSD drive (will make any system faster and more responsive).

Comment: I tried Ubuntu 16.04, and it was just as slow. I installed Ubuntu MATE. It sat on a blank screen for 4 minutes before reaching the login screen (just like Ubuntu 18), but after that I ran faster.